# Control python class remotely

Tags: python, python-2.7, remote-access

I made python class that controls my sound system in my house, the class looks like that:

```
from django.db import models
import youtube_dl, pygame, glob

class PlayerControl(object):
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.mixer.init()
    def download_music(self, video_url):
        ydl_opts = {
            'format': 'bestaudio/best',
            'postprocessors': [{
            'key': 'FFmpegExtractAudio',
            'preferredcodec': 'mp3',
            'preferredquality': '192',
            }],
            'forcefilename': True,
        }
        ydl = youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(ydl_opts);
        ydl.download(video_url)
    def get_mp3_files_list(self):
        return glob.glob("*.mp3")
    def play_music(self, fileName):
        pygame.mixer.music.load("1.mp3")
        pygame.mixer.music.play()
    def pause(self):
        pygame.mixer.music.pause()
    def replay(self):
        pygame.mixer.music.play()
    def get_volume(self):
        return pygame.mixer.music.get_volume()
    def set_volume(self, volume_to_set):
        pygame.mixer.music.set_volume(volume_to_set)
```

To take a step forward, I wanted to make kind of an interface the controls this class remotely, using a better interface compared to python shell...

I guess that controlling it via a browser would be the simplest thing to do,
My question is - how to I modify python classes from a browser, using HTTP requests.

Comment: You want to send http requests to invoke the various methods of this class, or send python code for execution?

Comment: I want to send http requests to invoke the various methods of this class.

Comment: @Itay I hope my answer has helped you, if you are still in need of help, please let me know how it might be useful to expand my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to control this over http, you'll need to take what you have and build a web-accessible API. The standard industry practice for this at the moment wild be a REST API, but for your first attempt I wouldn't get caught up in the details.

I would recommend that you start with a micro framework such as Bottle or Flask. The good news is that you have already written the model you want to interact with, now you simply need to hook it up to something.

Following the MVC pattern, you will want to write a View layer which takes information from your model, or from the return value of its methods, and displays it in a way you wish to consume. Then write a controller using your web micro framework of choice, which binds the model and view together such that when you make a http request on a given endpoint it calls the relevant methods and returns the relevant data.

I've kept everything at a high level here, but would be happy to answer specific questions from comments.

Comment: Thank you. Between Bottle and Flask, what would you suggest to start with?

Comment: I'd say it depends: if all you want is to expose a rest API bottle will do everything you want, and it has no dependencies; If you're looking to build any web pages to go with it then you might want to look at flask, it uses Jinja2 which is a great templating library, and has a larger community for support. If you want to go all out and dive in at the deep end you could try Django, but I think it does far more than you need for this project, and could add some unnecessary complexity.